# Are elders required to be old?

Tags: titus

In Titus 1 Paul tells Titus to appoint elders in the cities of Crete. In chapter 2 Paul gives instructions for older men and women. Though the words are different (presbuteros vs presbutos) they are obviously related. 
My question is, should elders be old? Is there some kind of age requirement for being an elder, and how is that age determined?

Comment: _Presbuteros_ [Strong 4245](https://biblehub.com/greek/4245.htm) occurs in Titus 1:5 which I assume is where you are asking from. 'Elder women' are referred to (see I Timothy 5:2) but only in regard to age, not office. Could you give some references to the verses you are quoting about 'older men and women'. I am not clear as to what you are referencing. The term refers to maturity, in context it is significant maturity. The only mentions of age I can think of are widows to be financially supported only after threescore years and Paul's mention of himself being 'aged' again, when over sixty.

Comment: This looks more like a question asking how this passage should be applied today, which makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As the word implies elder actually refers to... you guessed it - to elder (person). In the Old Testament, “elder” usually translates the Hebrew word zaqen from a root which means “beard”. In the New Testament, the Greek word is presbuteros  "presbus ‘old (man)’", which is transliterated in English as “presbyter” and from which the word “priest” was derived.
In the Hebrew language the word 'elder' and 'beard' are near identical. If you don't have a beard you were not "elder" material. To the Hebrews it basically meant "experienced" and capable of dealing with other people's problems. This changed when the beardless Greeks came and the old words lost their meaning. Suddenly beard was no longer the sign of maturity and experience. The Bible almost never defines age limits in any category (including marriage).

Comment: I would want to see some substantiation here, especially regarding Hebrew and Greek words. Just a link to Biblehub would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

*Are elders required to be old*? **Yes**, but *how old*? In the Scriptures there is no defined age to be an elder, but in 1 Timothy 3:4 and Titus 1:6, Paul gives rules to the office of bishop, that will allow us to determine the age of an elder.

> **One that ruleth well his own house, having his children in subjection** with all gravity; [*1 Timothy 3:4*]

> If any be blameless, the husband of one wife, having faithful **children not accused of riot or unruly**. [*Titus 1:6*]

In these verses, it is indicated that he must be a man old enough to have raised children and that they (*the children*) could demonstrate their good testimony and obedience to authority, therefore, they should be mature.

Thus, the aspiring presbyter had to show that he had raised decent children, obedient to the faith and to their father. So, it can be deduced that he was a man not less than **45 years old**, considering an adult from the age of 20 (*Exodus 30:14; 38:26; Numbers 1:3, 20; 32:11*)